# How can i render ngx-quill editor content from my database to a view component?

Tags: javascript, angular, ngx-quill

I'm working on an angular blog app that uses ngx-quill as a text editor. I had no trouble adding records to my database. the problem occurs when I try to render content, it's not showing the data.

this is my details-post component HTML where I want to show content:

```html
<article class="post" *ngIf="post$ | async as post; else loading">
<div class="post-thumbnail" style="background-image: url(&quot;https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1538370965046-79c0d6907d47?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=750&q=80&quot;);" >
  <h1 class="post-title">{{ post.titlePost }}</h1>
  <div class="post-meta">February 20, 2020</div>
</div>

<div class="blog-post-content">
  {{ post.contentPost }}
</div>

</article>

<ng-template #loading>
  <div class="container-spinner">
    <mat-spinner></mat-spinner>
  </div>
</ng-template>
```

Answer (score 3):

For *ngx-quill* you have to either use their own [directive](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngx-quill#quillviewcomponent-quillviewhtmlcomponent--how-to-present-the-editor-content):

`<quill-view [content]="content" format="text" theme="snow"></quill-view>`

or `innerHTML`. [More info here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngx-quill#quillviewhtmlcomponent---using-angular-innerhtml)

```
<div class="ql-container ql-snow" style="border-width: 0;">
  <div class="ql-editor" [innerHTML]="byPassedHTMLString">
  </div>
</div>
```

I would suggest using their own directive.

Cheers

Comment: I tried using quill directive as you suggested but still not working. I wonder if you could share some example code for this configuration.

Comment: @Faustoma for sure! Here ya go https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-grzbcw?file=src/app/app.component.ts

Answer (score 1):

use "quill-view-html" component provided by ngx-quill editor. Add your content that you got from db in [content]="your content", check all the configaration [here](https://github.com/KillerCodeMonkey/ngx-quill?tab=readme-ov-file) (go to bottom of the page).

```
<quill-view-html class="mobile-preview-content" [content]="post.contentPost" theme="snow" sanitize="true"></quill-view-html>
```